# How to get a simple text in AJAX response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've been looking all around for this answer, there are some posts that have similar questions but their answers did not work for me. My ultimate goal is to populate a drop down list based on what the user select in another drop down list. After some research I determined it was a good idea to use AJAX, so I'm progressing with baby steps in order to learn AJAX. So I have not been able to get a simple text answer, I do get the answer but the whole page HTML comes appended to the answer. How would I go about getting a simple and clean text answer using AJAX?

Here is my php code:

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest' &&
    isset($_POST["OM"]) && !empty($_POST["OM"])){

    $OM = $_POST["OM"];
    switch($OM) {
        case "CMO": test_function(); break;
    }

}

function test_function(){
    $return = $_POST;
    $return["posto"] = "Sargento";

    $return["json"] = json_encode($return);
    echo json_encode($return);
}
?>
```

The javascript looks like this:

```
$('#om-dropdown').change(function () {
        var id = $(this).val();
        var data = {
            "OM": id
        }
        data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            data: data,
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                console.log(arguments);
                console.warn(xhr.responseText)
                alert(" Can't do because: " + error);
            },
            success:function(data){    
                alert("Form submitted successfully.\nReturned json: " + data["json"]);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

However, when I execute the javascript the AJAX response is as follows:

```
Arguments(3) [{…}, "parsererror", SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 116
```

I did some research on that error, and a user suspected it was beacause there was HTML embeded in the AJAX answer, so he suggested adding `console.warn(xhr.responseText)` to the error log, and sure enough I got:

```
{"account":"CMO","OM":"CMO","posto":"Sargento","json":"{\"account\":\"CMO\",\"OM\":\"CMO\",\"posto\":\"Sargento\"}"}<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>ASC | Principal</title>

    <link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    [HTML CONTINUES]
```

But as you can see, the answer I was expecting is in the first line of the response. How can I get clean answer with just the JSON? Thank you.

Comment: Read the rest of the html. does it refer to any php error? that html should not be there and invalidates the json response

Comment: If there was an error, it shouldn't return a 200, so the ajax call wouldn't try and parse it.  But it's php... so...

Comment: The linked question suggests adding `exit();` or that you are possibly including `master.php`

Comment: It does not refer to any php erros, I could post the whole html, but it is 200 lines long, maybe it is not necessary.

Comment: Is this running part of some framework that may be continuing on and rendering a view?

Comment: It is not part of a framework, adding the suggested 'exit()' did it! Can you post it as an answer @freedomn-m

Comment: The `exit();` would only help if there _was_ something happening after the code you're showing.